# Enable Phone settings using react-native

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I want to turn on Location/GPS if location was turned off .Is this possible to achieve this using **react-native** ? .I searched this on many sites  , they told me to do the changes in Java files , so that is not possible for my app . My app is created by Pure react-native codes so someone please guide/refer me on this .

Comment: on iOS only the user can turn location on/off through the device settings.

Comment: ok then . .For android ?

Answer (score 1):

you can try [react-native-system-setting](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-system-setting)

It provides some system setting APIs for you. Support iOS and Android both.

Support

- Volume ( with listener)
- Brightness
- Wifi switch
- Location
- Bluetooth

Comment: i got unexpected token error while using above example  .. `SystemSetting.isLocationEnabled()`

Comment: are you using real device?

Comment: Yes .testing them now in my Android mobile

Comment: i update my question with my error . .pls see that @Mohamed

Comment: the library is still maintained you can tell them about this issue in example here https://github.com/c19354837/react-native-system-setting/issues/new

Comment: can you add it in another question please

Comment: Ok adding it now .

Comment: pls see this , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46344869/got-unexpected-token-error-while-using-react-native-system-setting