# Got UnExpected token error while using react-native-system-setting

Tags: android, react-native

For enabling location in Phone i used `react-native-system-setting` . But while using that i got unexpected token error . can some one clarify me  , how to use this in react native codes .

```js
// this is my error


Unexpected token (12:15)
  10 |   };
  11 | 
> 12 |   SystemSetting.isLocationEnabled().then((enable)=>{
     |                ^
  13 |     const state = enable ? 'On' : 'Off';
  14 |     console.log('Current location is ' + state);
  15 | })
```

```js
// this is my CODE



import React, { Component } from "react";
import SystemSetting from 'react-native-system-setting';


export default class PhoneSetting extends Component {


  SystemSetting.isLocationEnabled().then((enable)=>{
  // got error on above line
    const state = enable ? 'On' : 'Off';
    console.log('Current location is ' + state);
})

 SystemSetting.switchLocation(()=>{
    console.log('switch location successfully');
})

  render() {
    var self = this;
    return (
      <View>
      // some content
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you should wrap it in `constructor()` or `componentWillMount()`

also `SystemSetting.switchLocation()` should be only call it when the `SystemSetting.isLocationEnabled()` return false if you want to enable it

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import SystemSetting from 'react-native-system-setting';


export default class PhoneSetting extends Component {

constructor() {
 super();
   SystemSetting.isLocationEnabled().then((enable)=>{
  // got error on above line
    const state = enable ? 'On' : 'Off';
    console.log('Current location is ' + state);
   })

  SystemSetting.switchLocation(()=>{
    console.log('switch location successfully');
  })
}
render() {
  var self = this;
  return (
   <View>
    // some content
    </View>
 );
}
}
```

Comment: got this error --->  TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'SystemSettingNative.isLocationEnabled')

Comment: did you linked the library?

Comment: Yeah , For linking i used this---> react-native link react-native-android-location-services-dialog-box

Comment: try with manual linking and follow this here https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-system-setting#android

Comment: i dnt have those settings.gradle file in my app . It is just a pure native app . i dnt have any folder called Android or Ios !!!

Comment: you can also try react-native link without the name you may mis spilled it's name

Comment: are you use expo? if yes you cannot use this library with expo expo not able to use native code  you need to create your project with native code not from quick start http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.48/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: Still no use bro :( --> Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'SystemSettingNative.isLocationEnabled')